# parsing the multiple hierarchy json file

Tags: c#, json

i am new to json parsing in .net.

i am trying to filter the json file to get records only where _type": "MONITOR_PROCESS_STATUS".

My code is :

```
 public void LoadJson()
           {
                using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("application_metrics.json"))
                {
                    string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                    var jsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
                    Console.ReadLine();

                }
            }
```

When i try to access the _type from the object, it throws an error.
How does the filter works in this scenario?

My json file:

```
[{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 2,
      "successful": 2,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 20,
      "max_score": null,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "logstash-tramslogcidr-w-2015.14",
            "_type": "MONITOR_JVM_DETAIL",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "instancename": "AlertRulesGUI_27.1.0_9012",
               "cpuTime": 100000000,
               "appName": "NodeAgent",
               "instanceName": "NodeAgent_27.1.4_8898",
               "appname": "AlertRulesGUI",
               "appNamespace": "dr"
            },
            "sort": [
               1427993199389,
               1427993199389
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "logstash-tramslogcidr-w-2015.14",
            "_type": "MONITOR_PROCESS_STATUS",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "state": "RUNNING",
               "instanceName": "NodeAgent_27.1.4_8898",
               "instancename": "AlertRulesGUI_27.1.0_9012",
               "appname": "AlertRulesGUI",
               "appnamespace": "dr"
            },
            "sort": [
               1427993199389,
               1427993199389
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "logstash-tramslogcidr-w-2015.14",
            "_type": "MONITOR_TOMCAT_APPLICATION_DETAIL",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "date": "Thu Apr 02 11:46:39 CDT 2015",
               "intervalTime": 61502,
               "@timestamp": 1427993199389,
               "instanceGroup": "site_b",
               "machinename": "c111ngw",
               "machine": "c111ngw",
               "appName": "NodeAgent",
               "gc_collection_count": 0,
               "instanceName": "NodeAgent_27.1.4_8898",
               "instancename": "AlertRulesGUI_27.1.0_9012",
               "appname": "AlertRulesGUI",
               "cpuTime": 100000000
            },
            "sort": [
               1427993199389,
               1427993199389
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "logstash-tramslogcidr-w-2015.14",
            "_type": "MONITOR_PROCESS_STATUS",
            "_id": "8786957a-e90d-4f49-ae6a-3279f6190575",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "state": "Orphan",
               "instanceName": "NodeAgent_27.1.4_8898",
               "instancename": "AlertRulesGUI_12.6.4_9004",
               "appname": "AlertRulesGUI",
               "appnamespace": "dr"
            },
            "sort": [
               1427993198443,
               1427993198443
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "logstash-tramslogcidr-w-2015.14",
            "_type": "MONITOR_PROCESS_STATUS",
            "_id": "8ffba1e8-5220-4d06-b452-d90f30e2629e",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "state": "RUNNING",
               "instanceName": "NodeAgent_27.1.4_8898",
               "instancename": "AlertRulesGUI_27.1.0_9012",
               "appname": "AlertRulesGUI",
               "appnamespace": "dr"
            },
            "sort": [
               1427993137887,
               1427993137887
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "logstash-tramslogcidr-w-2015.14",
            "_type": "MONITOR_JVM_DETAIL",
            "_id": "61353952-833e-4aa4-b9fe-bacbe92fdd30",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
                "instancename": "AlertRulesGUI_21.1.0_9012",
               "cpuTime": 100000000,
               "appName": "NodeAgent",
               "instanceName": "NodeAgent_21.1.4_8898",
               "appname": "AlertRulesGUI",
               "appNamespace": "dr"
            },
            "sort": [
               1427993137886,
               1427993137886
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "logstash-tramslogcidr-w-2015.14",
            "_type": "MONITOR_TOMCAT_APPLICATION_DETAIL",
            "_id": "cb762377-abfb-4121-b79a-c0c13af7af26",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "date": "Thu Apr 02 11:46:39 CDT 2015",
               "intervalTime": 61502,
               "@timestamp": 1427993199389,
               "instanceGroup": "site_b",
               "machinename": "c112ngw",
               "machine": "c112ngw",
               "appName": "NodeAgent",
               "gc_collection_count": 0,
               "instanceName": "NodeAgent_27.1.4_8898",
               "instancename": "AlertRulesGUI_27.1.0_9013",
               "appname": "AlertRulesGUI",
               "cpuTime": 120000000
            },
            "sort": [
               1427993137884,
               1427993137884
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "logstash-tramslogcidr-w-2015.14",
            "_type": "MONITOR_PROCESS_STATUS",
            "_id": "7dea06de-6c15-480e-9adb-0353e2d1ffcb",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "state": "Orphan",
               "instanceName": "NodeAgent_27.1.4_8898",
               "instancename": "AlertRulesGUI_12.6.4_9004",
               "appname": "AlertRulesGUI",
               "appnamespace": "dr"
            },
            "sort": [
               1427993136929,
               1427993136929
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "logstash-tramslogcidr-w-2015.14",
            "_type": "MONITOR_TOMCAT_APPLICATION_DETAIL",
            "_id": "bc70d4ec-d81a-473a-9e48-3ef6c6cd52e8",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
              "date": "Thu Apr 02 11:46:39 CDT 2015",
               "intervalTime": 61502,
               "@timestamp": 1427993199389,
               "instanceGroup": "site_b",
               "machinename": "c111ngw",
               "machine": "c111ngw",
               "appName": "NodeAgent",
               "gc_collection_count": 0,
               "instanceName": "NodeAgent_27.1.4_8898",
               "instancename": "AlertRulesGUI_27.1.0_9012",
               "appname": "AlertRulesGUI",
               "cpuTime": 100000000
            },
            "sort": [
               1427993076267,
               1427993076267
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "logstash-tramslogcidr-w-2015.14",
            "_type": "MONITOR_JVM_DETAIL",
            "_id": "48c33ef4-36a9-4e0d-8949-1e48083ff9a2",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
                 "instancename": "AlertRulesGUI_27.1.0_9012",
               "cpuTime": 100000000,
               "appName": "NodeAgent",
               "instanceName": "NodeAgent_27.1.4_8898",
               "appname": "AlertRulesGUI",
               "appNamespace": "dr"
            },
            "sort": [
               1427993076267,
               1427993076267
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "logstash-tramslogcidr-w-2015.14",
            "_type": "MONITOR_PROCESS_STATUS",
            "_id": "d1dd74bd-e9dc-436b-8343-afff23bceaa7",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "state": "RUNNING",
               "instanceName": "NodeAgent_18.1.4_8898",
               "instancename": "AlertRulesGUI_0.1.0_9012",
               "appname": "AlertRulesGUI1",
               "delete_status": "false",
               "appNamespace": "dr",
               "appnamespace": "dr"
            },
            "sort": [
               1427993076267,
               1427993076267
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "logstash-tramslogcidr-w-2015.14",
            "_type": "MONITOR_PROCESS_STATUS",
            "_id": "302701d4-3e8e-45ef-a903-5819a82c96a7",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "state": "Orphan",
               "instanceName": "NodeAgent_27.1.4_8898",
               "instancename": "AlertRulesGUI_12.6.4_9004",
               "appname": "AlertRulesGUI",
               "appnamespace": "dr"
            },
            "sort": [
               1427993075351,
               1427993075351
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "logstash-tramslogcidr-w-2015.14",
            "_type": "MONITOR_JVM_DETAIL",
            "_id": "d2b6a3f7-77ed-49b8-9887-4bbbbaf5cc6f",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
                "instancename": "AlertRulesGUI_1.1.0_9012",
               "cpuTime": 100000000,
               "appName": "NodeAgent",
               "instanceName": "NodeAgent_17.1.4_8898",
               "appname": "AlertRulesGUI",
               "appNamespace": "dr"
            },
            "sort": [
               1427993014705,
               1427993014705
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "logstash-tramslogcidr-w-2015.14",
            "_type": "MONITOR_PROCESS_STATUS",
            "_id": "2fa21507-53bf-469f-96ec-e9be3a5726b9",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "state": "RUNNING",
               "instanceName": "NodeAgent_27.1.4_8898",
               "instancename": "AlertRulesGUI_27.1.0_9012",
               "appname": "AlertRulesGUI",
               "appnamespace": "dr"
            },
            "sort": [
               1427993014705,
               1427993014705
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "logstash-tramslogcidr-w-2015.14",
            "_type": "MONITOR_TOMCAT_APPLICATION_DETAIL",
            "_id": "34b8c290-a2c5-43c5-84e7-31b97dfb95de",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "date": "Thu Apr 02 11:46:39 CDT 2015",
               "intervalTime": 61502,
               "@timestamp": 1427993299389,
               "instanceGroup": "site_b",
               "machinename": "c111ngw",
               "machine": "c111ngw",
               "appName": "NodeAgent",
               "gc_collection_count": 0,
               "instanceName": "NodeAgent_27.1.4_8898",
               "instancename": "AlertRulesGUI_28.1.0_9012",
               "appname": "AlertRulesGUI",
               "cpuTime": 130000000
            },
            "sort": [
               1427993014703,
               1427993014703
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "logstash-tramslogcidr-w-2015.14",
            "_type": "MONITOR_PROCESS_STATUS",
            "_id": "1d8bbcbe-1287-4809-a7b9-590a53b116c2",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "state": "Orphan",
               "instanceName": "NodeAgent_27.1.4_8898",
               "instancename": "AlertRulesGUI_12.6.4_9004",
               "appname": "AlertRulesGUI",
               "appnamespace": "dr"
            },
            "sort": [
               1427993013851,
               1427993013851
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "logstash-tramslogcidr-w-2015.14",
            "_type": "MONITOR_JVM_DETAIL",
            "_id": "2354a4ac-4e1b-4737-86c9-eb833af1c1ad",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
                "instancename": "AlertRulesGUI_27.1.0_9012",
               "cpuTime": 100000000,
               "appName": "NodeAgent",
               "instanceName": "NodeAgent_27.1.4_8898",
               "appname": "AlertRulesGUI",
               "appNamespace": "dr"
            },
            "sort": [
               1427992953259,
               1427992953259
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "logstash-tramslogcidr-w-2015.14",
            "_type": "MONITOR_PROCESS_STATUS",
            "_id": "476c574d-58f5-455d-9b4b-31f14f2e34f2",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "state": "RUNNING",
               "instanceName": "NodeAgent_27.1.4_8898",
               "instancename": "AlertRulesGUI_27.1.0_9012",
               "appname": "AlertRulesGUI",
               "appnamespace": "dr"
            },
            "sort": [
               1427992953259,
               1427992953259
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "logstash-tramslogcidr-w-2015.14",
            "_type": "MONITOR_TOMCAT_APPLICATION_DETAIL",
            "_id": "f1978558-8c35-45a3-9c34-e5c5726b3a94",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "date": "Thu Apr 02 11:46:39 CDT 2015",
               "intervalTime": 61502,
               "@timestamp": 1427993199389,
               "instanceGroup": "site_b",
               "machinename": "c111ngw",
               "machine": "c111ngw",
               "appName": "NodeAgent",
               "gc_collection_count": 0,
               "instanceName": "NodeAgent_27.1.4_8898",
               "instancename": "AlertRulesGUI_27.1.0_9012",
               "appname": "AlertRulesGUI",
               "cpuTime": 180000000
            },
            "sort": [
               1427992953257,
               1427992953257
            ]
         },
         {
            "_index": "logstash-tramslogcidr-w-2015.14",
            "_type": "MONITOR_PROCESS_STATUS",
            "_id": "94a4a6d2-0df7-465c-9edf-8e4b7044e78c",
            "_score": null,
            "_source": {
               "state": "Orphan",
               "instanceName": "NodeAgent_27.1.4_8898",
               "instancename": "AlertRulesGUI_12.6.4_9004",
               "appname": "AlertRulesGUI",
              "appnamespace": "dr"
            },
            "sort": [
               1427992952437,
               1427992952437
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
]
```

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: For starters you should use  var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<yourType>(json); what you have written is the other way around...

Comment: What error does it throw? How are you attempting to access `_type` ?

Comment: Theres a nice tool to see the structure: http://www.jsontree.com/

Comment: With that structure you can start to build your classes...

Comment: Alternative you could use Linq2Json :http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class YourType
{
    [JsonProperty("took")]
    public int Took { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timed_out")]
    public bool TimedOut { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("_shards")]
    public Shard  Shards { get; set; }

    // and so on and so on
}

class Shard
{
    [JsonProperty("total")]
    public int Total { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("successful")]
    public int SuccessFul { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("failed")]
    public int Failed { get; set; }
}
```

Then to deserialze:

```
IEnumerable<YourType> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<YourType>>(File.ReadAllText(path));
```

Comment: IEnumerable<YourType> because your json is an array (  [ ... ]  )

Comment: true we need to make it as IEnumerable<YourType>. The error has vanished.